# how to highlight text in uitextview in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview

Can any one help me how to highlight text in a `UITextView`. The text is coming from `sqlite`. I have implemented a search with `UISearchBar`. I need to highlight texts related the search result.

Comment: How about asking this question on google.com ?

Comment: One good tutorial is http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution is use [Core Text Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html). It is very powerful but it require some knowledge to use.

There is no other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is other way for iOS 7 and up. It's by using TextKit framework.
Simple tutorial with examples can be found here: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/getting-to-know-textkit.html